# what happened to html <tab id=name> functionality

Tags: html

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/tabs.html

wanted to do some as concise as possible html, but this does not seem to work in current firefox, has it been dropped? or do I need to specify some html level or something in some other control header?

Comment: html3? that's dead/gone...

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? I would recommend using a HTML5 alternative; HTML3 was only ever a working draft. Even browsers at the time only adopted some parts, never mind modern browsers where it's hardly supported at all. You probably want the `pre` tag, but without more information it's hard to help.

Comment: Thanks, yeah using <pre> at the moment, I think I may use some inline css columns, they seem to provide some nice features.